# Dependent or independent? Before and after teaching

Tags: independence

If I measure the performance of a group of students before and after teaching them, but the population size of the pre-teaching group is 30 and the population size of the post-teaching group is 15, are these populations dependent or independent?

The 15 in the post-teaching group were also in the pre-teaching group but not everyone participated in the post-teaching quiz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat scores from the enduring 15 as a paired sample, provided you have the required information to match the pre- and post-teaching scores.
In that case you would use a paired t test if scores are numerical and a paired Wilcoxon (signed-rank) test if scores are ordinal levels of comparable categorical variables.

(It might be interesting to see if pre-teaching scores from the 15 subjects that did not participate in the post-teaching quiz differed from the the pre-teaching scores of the others.)

*Addendum* per Comments: For normally distributed test scores
here are the results of a paired test and a two-sample test
on the same data.

First, if data are paired (illustrative data sampled using R),
a paired t test gives a highly significant result.

```
set.seed(2020)
x.pre = round(rnorm(15, 70, 5))
x.pst = x.pre + round(rnorm(15, 3, 2))
t.test(x.pre, x.pst, pair=T)

        Paired t-test

data:  x.pre and x.pst
t = -6.4386, df = 14, p-value = 1.552e-05
alternative hypothesis: 
   true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -4.177088 -2.089579
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
              -3.133333
```

Here is a 'stripchart' (dotplot) of the 15 differences, which are
clearly not centered at $0.$

```
stripchart(x.pst-x.pre, meth="stack", pch=20)
```

[image]

Second, trying to interpret the data as two independent samples,
a two-sample t test (improper procedure) finds no difference.

```
t.test(x.pst, x.pre)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x.pst and x.pre
t = 1.3082, df = 27.381, p-value = 0.2017
alternative hypothesis: 
   true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.777814  8.044481
sample estimates:
 mean of x mean of y 
  74.86667  71.73333
```

Here is a plot of 15 pre-teaching and 15 post-teaching scores. For my hypothetical data, it is not clear whether the two samples have different locations. The variability among students masks the
relatively small difference between group means.

```
stripchart(list(x.pre, x.pst), ylim=c(.5, 2.7), meth="stack", pch=20)
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot match the two samples as I did not take identifying information. Does this mean the samples are independent? 

Also the data is not normally distributed so I can't use a t-test surely?

Comment: If you can't match subjects pre and post, then testing is difficult. The pre and post samples are obviously not independent because the same subjects are involved. // With only 15 subjects it is often difficult to say for sure whether or nor data are normal.

Comment: Are there any tests I can perform then to see if there is a statistically significant difference between the two groups?

Comment: None that come to mind. It is best to plan out data analysis in advance of staring a study. // Maybe someone will have an idea that escapes me.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)